# Set DataGridView Cell Value from a SubClass Value

Tags: c#, datagridview, subclass

assuming that i have a class like below:

```
public class Origin {
    public Origin(bool isAllowed, bool isGloballyAllowed) {
        IsAllowed = isAllowed;
        IsGloballyAllowed = isGloballyAllowed;
    }

    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
    public bool IsGloballyAllowed { get; set; }
}

public class OriginSet {
    public OriginSet() {
        OriginType = originType;
        OriginData_A = originDataA;
        OriginData_B = originDataB;
        OriginData_C = originDataC;
    }

    public string OriginType { get; set; }
    public Origin OriginData_A { get; set; }
    public Origin OriginData_B { get; set; }
    public Origin OriginData_C { get; set; }
}
```

and i have a `List<OriginSet>` variable with below values:

```
var originList = new List<OriginSet> {
    new OriginSet("Origin 1", new Origin(true, true), new Origin(true, false), new Origin(false, false),
    new OriginSet("Origin 2", new Origin(false, false), new Origin(true, false), new Origin(true, true)
};
```

How can i display it in a DataGridView with below layout:

[image]

The idea is that the CheckBoxes in the DataGridView has their `ThreeState` property enabled so that it is available in 3 different values, whereas it is dependent on the value of the `Origin` Class that is a Property of the `OriginSet` Class, as below:

```
(IsAllowed = TRUE and IsGloballyAllowed = TRUE) THEN CheckBox is Checked
(IsAllowed = TRUE and IsGloballyAllowed = FALSE) THEN CheckBox is Indeterminate
(IsAllowed = FALSE and IsGloballyAllowed = FALSE) THEN CheckBox is Unchecked
```

I would like to reach out for some help, as this will be my first time to do such a thing, also if it is even allowable. I've tried looking up google but no results matched my specific question.

Comment: how are you binding data to data grid view normally ?

Comment: i normally would pass the List itself as the DataSource for the DataGridView with the columns having a DataPropertyName to bind with the variable's class' property name.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is doable however; I am guessing you may have to approach this differently.

Looking at the picture, specifically the column “Data A”… is a check box column. Each check box cell in this column is data bound to an `Origin` object. This `Origin` object has two (2) bool properties: `IsAllowed` and `IsGloballyAllowed.` The grid isn’t going to know which one to display even if they are publicly exposed. In addition, the “logic” you described…

```
(IsAllowed = TRUE and IsGloballyAllowed = TRUE) THEN CheckBox is Checked
(IsAllowed = TRUE and IsGloballyAllowed = FALSE) THEN CheckBox is Indeterminate
(IsAllowed = FALSE and IsGloballyAllowed = FALSE) THEN CheckBox is Unchecked
```

is missing from the `Origin` Class. The point here, the check box cells can only take ONE (1) value and it is offered two (2). The logic above is what you need to implement to return the desired check state. The `Origin` class below demonstrates one way you could achieve this.

```
class Origin {
  public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
  public bool IsGloballyAllowed { get; set; }

  public Origin(bool isAllowed, bool isGloballyAllowed) {
    IsAllowed = isAllowed;
    IsGloballyAllowed = isGloballyAllowed;
  }

  public bool? CheckState {
    get {
      if (IsAllowed && IsGloballyAllowed)
        return true;
      if (!IsAllowed && !IsGloballyAllowed)
        return false;
      //if (IsAllowed == true && IsGloballyAllowed == false)
      //  return null;
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Added is a getter/property method `CheckState` that returns a nullable bool: `true`, `false` or `null` This is the property the class `OriginSet` can use to “expose” the `CheckedState` to the `DatagridView` and set the check boxes properly. Therefore, some changes are needed in the `OriginSet` class.

In the `OriginSet` Class it is already known that “exposing” an `Origin` object to a cell will not work. Therefore, one possible solution is to create valid `bool?` variables that “will” work when exposed to the grids check box. Once added to the class then initialized in the constructor using each `Origin` objects `CheckState` property, we can use the variables to set the check boxes properly.

```
class OriginSet {
  public string OriginType { get; set; }
  public Origin OriginData_A { get; set; }
  public Origin OriginData_B { get; set; }
  public Origin OriginData_C { get; set; }
  public bool? originA_State { get; set; }
  public bool? originB_State { get; set; }
  public bool? originC_State { get; set; }

  public OriginSet(string originType, Origin originDataA, Origin originDataB, Origin originDataC) {
    OriginType = originType;
    OriginData_A = originDataA;
    OriginData_B = originDataB;
    OriginData_C = originDataC;
    originA_State = originDataA.CheckState;
    originB_State = originDataB.CheckState;
    originC_State = originDataC.CheckState;
  }
}
```

With these changes, all that is needed is to set the `DataGridview` columns properly. Not much here but important points would be that when adding a column to the grid its `DataPropertyName` must match the name of the property in the `OriginSet` class in addition to setting the `ThreeState` to true to enable a `null` value. Lastly set the `AutoGenerateColumns` to false to prevent the grid from trying to display all the “public/exposed” properties in the `OriginSet` class.

```
List<OriginSet> originList;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FillList();
  SetGridProperties();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = originList;
}

private void FillList() {
  originList = new List<OriginSet> {
    new OriginSet("Origin 0", new Origin(true, true), new Origin(true, true), new Origin(true, true)),
    new OriginSet("Origin 1", new Origin(true, false), new Origin(true, false), new Origin(true, false)),
    new OriginSet("Origin 2", new Origin(false, false), new Origin(false, false), new Origin(false, false))
  };
}

private void SetGridProperties() {
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  txtCol.HeaderText = "Origin";
  txtCol.DataPropertyName = "OriginType";
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(txtCol);
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetCheckBoxCol("Data A", "originA_State"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetCheckBoxCol("Data B", "originB_State"));
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetCheckBoxCol("Data C", "originC_State"));
  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
}

private DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn GetCheckBoxCol(string name, string dataname) {
  DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chckCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
  chckCol.Name = name;
  chckCol.DataPropertyName = dataname;
  chckCol.ThreeState = true;
  return chckCol;
}
```

It should start becoming clear that there may be a problem here. That problem would be what do you plan on doing if the user “changes” a check box? These check boxes were determined by the initial values `isAllowed` and `isGloballyAllowed`…The point here is that the initial “logic” to “set” the `CheckState` will become “broken” when the user “changes” one of the check boxes. If you want to keep this logic correct, which I assume you would, you are going to have to do some more work to maintain that “logic.”

Hope this make sense and helps.